# Transformer for time series forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, pytorch, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning

I have discrete daily features and a target time series and I'm trying to implement a basic Transformer for seq2seq modeling. I construct my supervised data as follows:

```
 . . .\. . .\. . . .
       |
\0 0 0 0\0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The next sequence is shifted by one position ahead. Overall I have the input data shape `[batch_size, in_sequence_len, num_features]` and the target is `[batch_size, out_sequence_len, 1]`. I understand that encoder input should be of shape `[batch_size, in_seq_len, num_features]` and decoder takes `[batch_size, out_seq_len, num_features]`. But how should I transform my batch to be suitable for the transformer input?

Comment: Your input shape is `(batch_size, in_seq_len, num_features)` and the encoder shape is `(batch_size, in_seq_len, num_features)`, what's the matter?

Comment: The decoder has an input `[bs, out_seq, n_feat]` that starts with the last sample in the input sequence. I'm interested in how can I transform my current batches to be suitable for the decoder input.

Comment: I am not following you, your input shape is not `(batch_size, in_seq_len, num_features)`, then?

Comment: According to the original paper, we have two inputs to the model. Input to the encoder `[bs, in_seq_len, n_feat]` and input to the decoder `[bs, out_seq_len, n_feat]` which contains the 'future' points: i.e. (x_1,....x_10) to the encoder, (x_10, x_13) to the decoder. The output in this case will be (x_11, x_14).

Comment: Ok, could you please provide a small example with one sequence, and show us the desired ouput (I mean the tensor you would like to input to your model).